# Why does my dialogue box not show when fullscr=True?

Tags: python, user-interface, fullscreen, psychopy

I want to display a dialogue box to ask an experimental participant to enter a number, using psychopy. When `fullscr=False` in win, the dialogue box displays. When `fullscr=True`, it doesn't appear, even though typing the number and then return does progress the program to the next loop.

Any ideas why? Relevant code lines below.

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core, data, gui, logging
win = visual.Window([1024,768], fullscr=True, units='pix', autoLog=True)

respInfo={}
respInfo['duration']=''
respDlg = gui.DlgFromDict(respInfo)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the psychopy window is on top of everything else when `fullscr=True` so in your example, the dialogue box is created but not visible to the user since the window is on top.

## Present dialogue box in the beginning

If you just want a dialogue box in the beginning of the experiment, the solution is easy: show the dialogue box before creating the window:

```py
# Import stuff
from psychopy import visual, gui

# Show dialogue box
respInfo={'duration': ''}
respDlg = gui.DlgFromDict(respInfo)

# Initiate window
win = visual.Window(fullscr=True)
```

## Present dialogue box mid-way

You need a pretty convoluted hack if you want to show a dialogue midway during the experiment. You need to

1. close your current window,
2. show the dialogue box (optionally with a non-fullscreen window in the background to cover up your desktop)
3. create a new window (and close the optional window from step 2
4. set all stimuli to be rendered in the new window. Since the stimuli are pointing to the first window *object*, just creating a new window (new object) with the same variable name won't do the trick.

Here's some code that demos this approach with a single stimulus:

```py
# Import stuff, create a window and a stimulus
from psychopy import visual, event, gui
win1 = visual.Window(fullscr=True)
stim = visual.TextStim(win1)  # create stimulus in win1

# Present the stimulus in window 1
stim.draw()
win1.flip()
event.waitKeys()

# Present dialogue box
win_background = visual.Window(fullscr=False, size=[5000, 5000], allowGUI=False)  # optional: a temporary big window to hide the desktop/app to the participant
win1.close()  # close window 1
respDict = {'duration':''}
gui.DlgFromDict(respDict)
win_background.close()  # clean up the temporary background  

# Create a new window and prepare the stimulus
win2 = visual.Window(fullscr=True)
stim.win = win2  # important: set the stimulus to the new window.
stim.text = 'entered duration:' + respDict['duration']  # show what was entered

# Show it!
stim.draw()
win2.flip()
event.waitKeys()
```

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks. However I am already showing a message on the screen so the window has been created and displayed: I need the dialogue box partway through each trial routine. So would it make sense for me to `fullscr=False`, then show the dialogue box and then back to `fullscr=True`?

Comment: Ah, fun question. I updated the answer with a possible solution. I'm sure it's not as clean as you hoped for but at least it works :-)